# ScrollRect not scrolling when canvas Render Mode is set to Screen Space - Camera

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Did you find out why this was happening? I'm having the same issue here.

I had a canvas with a scroll bar working normally, I needed to set the canvas render mode to "Screen Space - Camera", and now the bar doesn't move anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you change the Canva's *Render Mode* from *Screen Space - Overlay* to *Screen Space - Camera*, an new slot called *Render Camera* will appear under the *Canvas*.  Drag your main camera into this slot. That camera will be used to send events to the UI elements.

[image]

---

If you've already done this but the problem is still there, delete the `ScrollRect` and create a new one. Finally, if the `ScrollRect` is still not moving, make sure that no other UI object is blocking it.

Maybe a hidden panel or image with 0 alpha... Any UI object that is below the `ScrollRect` in the **Hierarchy** tab will block the `ScrollRect` if on top of it.

**EDIT**:

Once you drag the main camera to the *Render Camera* slot, *Plane Distance* slot will appear. Also make sure that it's not set to 0. Mine is set to *100* as shown in the screenshot above and that should work fine.

Comment: Thank you, by default on Canvas was plane distance = 0, I set it to 1, and scrolling now work normal

Comment: @IgorCova The plane distance shouldn't be 0 by default. It should be around `100` as default.

Comment: Yes, I think someone changed that or we are using different Unity versions with different default values but glad you solved. Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

There might be multiple reasons why your scrollview doesn't work

1. I encountered with a similar problem. My **canvas** had a background image so i had to put a **Image** element without a sprite and set the alpha to "0" within *Content* of scrollview.[image]
2. when your viewport field is not referring to viewport object in scroll rect
3. Try altering the movement type

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem due to not having an EventSystem in the scene.